# clearTimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript, menu, sliding

Javascript sliding menu stay open. clearTimeout not working as expected -can you help me please

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#Menu1 {position:absolute;
 top:-190px; left:150px;
 font-size:15px;visibility:visible;
 background-color:#D0BCFE;
 width:114px;z-index:0;border-style:solid;
 }
#Menu2 {position:absolute;
 top:-190px; left:580px;
 font-size:15px;visibility:visible;
 background-color:#D0BCFE;
 width:114px;z-index:0;border-style:solid;
 }
#Menu3 {position:absolute;
 top:-190px; left:1005px;
 font-size:15px;visibility:visible;
 background-color:#D0BCFE;
 width:114px;z-index:0;border-style:solid;
 }

TD.TDHREFMENUS{font-size:20;color:red;position:relative;z-index:0;background-color:#C4ABFE;border-style:solid;width:114px;}
</style>
<script>

var stopUp=null;
var stopDown=null;
var mov=-143;
var on;

function down(id){

    if (!on){
       on=true;
       clearTimeout(stopUp)
       stopUp=null;
    }

    var obj=document.getElementById(id)
    obj.style.top=mov +"px";
    if (mov <=27){
       mov+=2;
       stopDown=setTimeout(function (){ down(id) }, 20)
    }
}

function up(id){

    if (on){
       on=false;
       clearTimeout(stopDown)
       stopDown=null; 
    }

    var obj=document.getElementById(id)
    obj.style.top=mov +"px";
    if (mov >=-143){
       mov-=2;
       stopUp=setTimeout(function(){ up(id)}, 20);
    }

}


</script>

</head>

<body leftmargin=0 marginwidth=0 topmargin=0 marginheight=0>


<div id="Menu1" onmouseover="down('Menu1')" onmouseout="up('Menu1')">
URL 1<br>
URL 2<br>
URL 3<br>
URL 4<br>
URL 5<br>
URL 6<br>
URL 7<br>
URL 8<br>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Menu2" onmouseover="down('Menu2')" onmouseout="up('Menu2')">
URL 1<br>
URL 2<br>
URL 3<br>
URL 4<br>
URL 5<br>
URL 6<br>
URL 7<br>
URL 8<br>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Menu3" onmouseover="down('Menu3')" onmouseout="up('Menu3')">
URL 1<br>
URL 2<br>
URL 3<br>
URL 4<br>
URL 5<br>
URL 6<br>
URL 7<br>
URL 8<br>
</div>
</div>

<TABLE cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 BORDER=1 WIDTH=100%>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD align=middle CLASS="TDHREFMENUS"><span onmouseover="down('Menu1')" onmouseout="up('Menu1')">MENU 1</span>
</TD>
<TD align=middle CLASS="TDHREFMENUS"><span onmouseover="down('Menu2')" onmouseout="up('Menu2')">MENU 2</span>
</TD>
<TD align=middle CLASS="TDHREFMENUS"><span onmouseover="down('Menu3')" onmouseout="up('Menu3')">MENU 3</span>
</TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<html>
<head>
```

EDIT:
When I tested it worked if I hovered over a single menu, but if I moved my mouse quickly over a few of the menus, the first one worked but the others menus also stop.

## Menu1  {position:absolute;

```
top:-190px; left:150px;
font-size:15px;visibility:visible;
background-color:#D0BCFE;
width:114px;z-index:0;border-style:solid;
}
```

## Menu2  {position:absolute;

```
top:-190px; left:580px;
font-size:15px;visibility:visible;
background-color:#D0BCFE;
width:114px;z-index:0;border-style:solid;
}
```

## Menu3  {position:absolute;

```
top:-190px; left:1005px;
font-size:15px;visibility:visible;
background-color:#D0BCFE;
width:114px;z-index:0;border-style:solid;
}
```

TD.TDHREFMENUS{font-size:20;color:red;position:relative;z-index:0;background-color:#C4ABFE;border-style:solid;width:114px;}

var stopUp=null;
var stopDown=null;
var mov=-143;
var on;

function down(id){

if (!on){
on=true;
clearTimeout(stopUp)
stopUp=null;

}

var obj=document.getElementById(id)
obj.style.top=mov +"px";
if (mov =-143){
mov-=2;
stopUp=setTimeout(function(){
up(id)}, 20);
}

}

URL 1
URL 2
URL 3
URL 4
URL 5
URL 6
URL 7
URL 8



URL 1
URL 2
URL 3
URL 4
URL 5
URL 6
URL 7
URL 8



URL 1
URL 2
URL 3
URL 4
URL 5
URL 6
URL 7
URL 8

MENU 1

MENU 2

MENU 3

Comment: It was way less horror without the code block...

Comment: That's hideous. use pre-made menu system.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<div>`s don't balance. You have two closing `</div>`s for every opening one.

Comment: True, and should be addressed, but I believe it's inconsequential to the problem experienced :-)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the timeout won't reset the object position -- **since the variable `mov` is shared, this will lead to problematic operations during transitions.** You get the "last" move value even though the new element being moved is not aligned accordingly.

*Possible Fixes:*

1. Always get the item position from the CSS value -- this will keep a per-item position (this is also how animation in jQuery works).
2. Keep a lookup (*or binding*) per item moving that maintains the position. Although, I would use the former as it's simpler. For the next part (maintaining the timer ids) #2 will used though :-)

In addition you will need to keep the timers running until an *operation* has been complete (not just a transition has occurred). That is, **the shared `stopUp` and `stopDown` values will lead to similar problems** as with the above shared `mov`. (This is handled transparently with jQuery animation queues). However, #1 from above does not work well here. So, let's explore using #2 *with closure bindings* -- this requires that the click events are attached in code.

```
function addFlyout (elm) {
   var timerId
   elm.onmouseover = function () {
      // now can use timerId and it will only be accessible
      // to things within *this* invocation of addFlyout, including
      // inside here.
      timerId = setTimeout(function () {
         ...
         if (needToDoMore) {
           // it's easy to reference the anonymous function inside
           // with arguments.callee. alternatively, setInterval could be used
           timerId = setTimeout(arguments.callee, ...)
         }
      }, ...);
   }
   elm.onmouseout = function () {
      // ditto
   }
}
...
addFlyout(document.getElementById("Menu1"))
```

[The Jibbering JS Closure Notes](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) contains lots of useful information. This approach could also be used for `mov`, but, as above, I think it's easier just to always get the current CSS value in that case.

Also, verify your markup (avoids other browser nonsense) and be aware of issues with onmouseover/out -- if the moved element moves over (or changes the shape of) the element handling the mouse events there can be issues with the events being triggered *or missed*.

*Using [jQuery](http://jquery.org) -- or a similar cross-browser framework -- can simplify the code and handle the above case trivially.* (jQuery even comes with a built-in animation function too!)

jQuery (without using a pre-made system), would look something similar to:

```
// get all elements to apply animation to
var elements = $("#Menu1").add("#Menu2").add("#Menu3")
elements.hover(function () { // over
  $(this).stop().animate({top: 140})
}, function () { // out
  $(this).stop().animate({top: 0})
})
```

Guess what I'd recommend :-)

Happy coding.